# Story Identification: Young adult sci-fi about teenagers born on the same day who are aliens

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a book I read in high school (around late 80's, early 90's). Its a young adult sci-fi  book about teenagers who were born on the same day and in the same hospital. All are best friends who start to develop powers (from what I can remember) and the title had the word '*experiment*' in it, I think. My searching has been unsuccessful!

Comment: I'm looking for that book, too! The kids all had different specialties/talents, like one was an artist, etc, and they started developing powers like psychic ability and mind reading. The eldest one started changing and getting weird, and the kids' investigation turned up that they were some (experiment?) from alien reptiles, and were slowly/quickly changing into reptiles themselves. The cover was a picture of the reflection of the kids' scared faces in the window of a car they're looking into with weird dudes inside, and I think the car was next to a barn in the middle of nowhere. (I also thin

Comment: Faint memories of "Twilight *something* " by Christopher Carpenter

Answer (score 5):

You may possibly be thinking of John Wyndham's *[The Midwich Cuckoos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Midwich_Cuckoos)*.

It's about 31 boys and 30 girls who were all born on the same day and when they grow up, they slowly develop all kinds of powers, such as mind control.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I looked at the book and that is not it. I remember there being only 7 teens and I don't remember it as having anyone killed. I'm thinking maybe it might have been short story in a larger connection, but I can't remember any more than that...

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Experiment in Terror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1075574.Experiment_in_Terror) by Bernal C Payne. The cover matches user3351's description. I read this book dozens of times in high school in the early 90's.

[image]

I've actually been looking for this book for a long time, so thanks for asking the question.

Comment: I think that's the one LoveToRead was looking for - it's definitely the one I was trying to remember. Thanks!